# npm install command fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next

Хочу подгрузить все dependencies для проекта но после небольшой загрузки выдает ошибку

````
npm ERR! path C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\romashko.g\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-5dc883ad.cmd
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\romashko.g\\vxnn\\teorema-front\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python38\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:400:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\romashko.g\\vxnn\\teorema-front\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\romashko.g\vxnn\teorema-front\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\romashko.g\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-31T08_05_54_800Z-debug-0.log```
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnpm%5D+node-sass

Answer (score 0):

первое проверь какой питон у тебя стоит, и какой нужен для проекта, просто он ищет 2 питон, а у тебя 3.8, так же посмотри есть ли он у тебя в path,
второе нашел подобную проблему на eng ресурсе.

Ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372618/npm-cant-find-python-executable-python-you-can-set-the-python-env-variabl

Посмотри тут, вдруг поможет)